# htaccess mod rewrite allow one domain without www and preserve one certain subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I´d like to point all possible entered domains to one certain base domain without www:

*www.example1.com

example2.net

example3.nl

etc.

( countless different... getting more)*

rewritten to >

*base-example.com*

here is the hook – 
There is a certain subdomain that should still be possible to be entered:

*subdom.base-example.de*

(that subdom. will be attached to a subfolder **/data/stuff/different**)

but in the adress bar there will always be shown **subdom.base-example.de** ( no subfolder info visible )

---

I tried:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^base-example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdom\.base-example\.com$ 
RewriteRule ^data/stuff/different/(.*)$ http://subdom.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^data/stuff/(.*)$ http://subdom.example.com/$1 [R=301]
RewriteRule ^data/(.*)$ http://subdom.example.com/$1 [R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdom\.base-example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://subdom.base-example.com/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^base-example\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://base-example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: So all domains except `subdom.base-example.de` should be redirected to `base-example.de`?

Comment: yes, that´s what it should be...
( and I don´t want to put 1 or 2 lines of code into the .htaccess file for each possible domain there... )


- - - -

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^base-example\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^subdom\.base-example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://base-example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! The code above really works. In combination with the following lines I add the subdomain invisibly gets data from the given folder tree:

  `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdom.base-example.com$`
  `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/data/stuff/different`
  `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /data/stuff/different/$1 [L]`

downsides:
a) all other subdomains are still applicable too<br>
b) the folders can be called and are visible in the urls<br>
   from the base-domain too
   ( base-example.com/data/stuff/... ) 

   I would like to have them invisible in the url...

Comment: That `invisible redirect` to me looks like you're changing the requirements via comments section which is not a good thing. Question should state everything you need not the comments.

Comment: Never mind – at least now I know how it´s called what I have to look for. ;) (invisible redirect/rewrite)
But I had that in my 1st question above though...

( anyway I will find a solution for that too cause - right now it might be producing duplicate content if the folders are browsable to from several domains )